# pjen - Simple static website generator

Tags: python, file

I've created a simple static website generator called pjen. The GitHub repository can be found [here](https://github.com/peajayni/pjen/tree/a7c51bc95c1e82c1a2bf86a9cff8e832138b110d).

```
import os

class pjen:
    def __init__(self, path=None):
        """
        By default, the path will be set to the current working directory, 
        or the path can be specified using the 'path' keyword parameter.
        """

        if path is None:
            self.path = os.getcwd() 
        else:
            self.path = path

        self.path += "/website"

    def create_project(self):
        """
        Creates an initial file structure for a project at the specified path. 

        An exception is raised if a project already exists in the desired location.

        Creates the following file structure:

        website
          |-> templates
              |-> group1
          |-> images
          |-> scss
          |-> css
          |-> scripts

        """

        if not os.path.exists(self.path):

            #make the root directory
            os.makedirs(self.path)

            os.makedirs(self.path+"/templates")
            os.makedirs(self.path+"/templates/group1")          
            os.makedirs(self.path+"/images")
            os.makedirs(self.path+"/scss")
            os.makedirs(self.path+"/css")
            os.makedirs(self.path+"/scripts")

            print("Created project in {}".format(self.path))

        else:
            raise IOError("A directory already exists at: {}".format(self.path))


    def _count_indent(self, str, tab_equiv=4):
        """
        Returns the number of leading spaces. A tab is counted as 'tab_equiv' spaces.
        """

        i = 0
        count = 0

        while(str[i] == " " or str[i] == "\t"):

            if str[i] == " ":
                count += 1
            if str[i] == "\t":
                count += 4

            i += 1

        return count

    def _sanatise_file_list(self, l, fname=None):
        """
        Removes blacklisted files from the input list 'l'. In addition, a file with 
        the name 'fname' can also be removed.
        """

        blacklist = [".DS_Store"]

        if fname:
            blacklist.append(fname)

        for item in blacklist:
            try:
                l.pop(l.index(item))
            except ValueError:
                pass

    def generate(self):
        """
        Iterates through all the directories in the 'templates' directory, inserting all the 
        inputs into each template. 
        """

        #get a list of template groups
        static_groups = os.listdir(self.path+"/templates")
        self._sanatise_file_list(static_groups)

        print("Found {} group(s)".format(len(static_groups)))

        #iterate through each of the template groups
        for group in static_groups:

            #get each of the files in the group
            files = os.listdir(self.path+"/templates/"+group)

            #remove the template and hidden file
            self._sanatise_file_list(files, "template.html")

            #open the template 
            with open(self.path+"/templates/" + group + "/template.html", "r") as template:

                #iterate though the files that need to be generated
                for f in files:

                    #create a new static page
                    with open(self.path + "/" + f, "w") as page:

                        print("Generating file: {}".format(f))

                        #open up the input
                        with open(self.path + "/templates/" + group + "/" + f, "r") as my_input:

                            #iterate through the input and extract the various sections
                            css = ""
                            html = ""
                            scripts = ""

                            #flag to determine the section of the input file
                            in_section = None

                            #iterate through the input file and set the appropriate flag
                            for line in my_input.readlines():
                                if line.lstrip().startswith("{{ css }}"):
                                    in_section = "css"
                                elif line.lstrip().startswith("{{ html }}"):
                                    in_section = "html"
                                elif line.lstrip().startswith("{{ scripts }}"):
                                    in_section = "scripts"
                                else:
                                    if in_section == "css":
                                        css += line
                                    if in_section == "html":
                                        html += line
                                    if in_section == "scripts":
                                        scripts += line


                            #reset the file pointer as the template can be read many times
                            template.seek(0)

                            #iterate through the template file
                            for line in template.readlines():

                                if line.lstrip().startswith("{{ css }}"):

                                    indent = self._count_indent(line)

                                    #if there is css in the input file then insert it
                                    if css != "":

                                        for insert_line in [x + "\n" for x in css.split("\n")]:

                                            page.write(" "*indent + insert_line)

                                #if there is html in the input file then insert it
                                elif line.lstrip().startswith("{{ html }}"):

                                    indent = self._count_indent(line)

                                    if html != "":

                                        for insert_line in [x + "\n" for x in html.split("\n")]:

                                            page.write(" "*indent + insert_line)

                                #if there are script links in the input file then insert them
                                elif line.lstrip().startswith("{{ scripts }}"):

                                    indent = self._count_indent(line)

                                    if scripts != "":

                                        for insert_line in [x + "\n" for x in scripts.split("\n")]:

                                            page.write(" "*indent + insert_line)

                                #otherwise copy the template text
                                else:
                                    page.write(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = pjen()
    p.generate()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_project` doesn't have the best name. It should be `create_project_folders` if you want to be exact. Even if you don't want to be verbose, you're `print` call should be clearer about what exactly it does. I would flip your test, and use `if os.path.exists(self.path)` to `raise IOError` so then the rest of the function doesn't need to nested. Note that it also shows the flow better. In pseudocode:

```
create_project function:
    if project folder exists:
        raise error

    make folders
```

Speaking of making the folders, you repeatedly call the same function with new strings each time. This is perfect place to use a `for` loop. In addition, the strings should really be constants. Probably a set of constants at the class level:

```
class pjen:

    PROJECT_FOLDERS = (
                        "/templates",
                        "/templates/group1",
                        "/images",
                        "/scss",
                        "/css",
                        "/scripts",
                      )
```

And now you can iterate over these folders to make them in `create_project`:

```
def create_project(self):

    if os.path.exists(self.path):
        raise IOError("A directory already exists at: {}".format(self.path))

    for folder in pjen.PROJECT_FOLDERS:
        os.makedirs(self.path + folder)

    print("Created project in {}".format(self.path))
```

Note that I haven't included `os.makedirs(self.path)`. That's because Python makes all the directories necessary, not just the last one in the list [(this is, in fact, why it's `makedirs` and not `makedir`)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs). In the same way, there's no need to call `os.makedirs(self.path + "/templates")` and `os.makedirs(self.path + "/templates/group1"), as the latter would create both folders. However I kept it as a constant so that you can see the full list of folders created as that can be more readable, and you may want/need to iterate over all project folders at some point.

Don't use `str` as a variable name, as it will shadow the built in `str` function. Using `string` is usually better. I also don't like `_count_indent` starting with an underscore. That's a convention to signal that the function is private and shouldn't be used externally. I don't see why that should be the case here, apart from that you don't *expect* people to need it. But I'd personally leave the underscore off.

`l` is a bad name for an input list, either `input_list` or `file_list` would be much better. If `fname` is `None` then it'll be fine as it just wont have any effect on a list of strings. Also instead of appending a single `fname` to `blacklist` you could make a tuple:

```
    blacklist = (".DS_Store", fname)
```

In fact I'd iterate directly over that rather than assigning it to blacklist.

Also you're using `pop` to remove items, but you can just use `remove`. `pop` returns the value after removing that, if you don't need that then you don't need `pop`.

```
def _sanatise_file_list(self, l, fname=None):
    """
    Removes blacklisted files from the input list 'l'. In addition, a file with 
    the name 'fname' can also be removed.
    """

    for item in (".DS_Store", fname):
        try:
            l.pop(l.index(item))
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

`generate` is *far* too long as a function. You should break it up into smaller functions. Ideally one job per function. This helps readability, clarity and testing.

Answer (score 5):

### `is` is broken:

```
>>> 1000 is 10**3
False
>>> 1000 == 10**3
True
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python), but in short it's better to use `==`.

---

### Ternary statements:

I really like ternaries, so I may be a little biased, but you can use ternary statements to simplify logic:

> ```
>     if path is None:
>         self.path = os.getcwd() 
>     else:
>         self.path = path
> ```

into:

```
    self.path = path if path != None else os.getcwd()
```

---

### `while` loop:

Instead of using a `while` loop, you can simply iterate using a `for` loop:

(also, Python does not require explicit brackets around the loop)

(also, `str[i]` cannot be both `" "` and `"\t"`, so you can use a `elif` for the second one.)

> ```
>     while(str[i] == " " or str[i] == "\t"):
>
>         if str[i] == " ":
>             count += 1
>         if str[i] == "\t":
>             count += 4
>
>         i += 1
>
>     return count
> ```

into:

```
    for item in str:
        if item == " ":
            count += 1
        elif item == "\t":
            count += 4

    return count
```

Comment: Your `for` loop isn't equivalent because you're not `break`ing when you encounter a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - I really like the ternary statements and plan to add these in. As @SuperBiasedMan alluded to, I've used the ```while``` loop as I thought it was cleaner.